# existence of finite-dimensional subspace containing a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and suppose we have a sequence $(x_n)$ which is bounded in $X$. Is it possible to find a finite-dimensional subspace $Y$ of $X$ such that $(x_n)\subset Y$?

Answer (score 4):

No, certainly not.  For instance, let $(w_n)$ be any sequence of linearly independent elements of $X$ and let $x_n=w_n/\|w_n\|$.  Then $(x_n)$ is bounded by linearly independent, so it cannot be contained in any finite-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Would it be possible if we consider a reflexive Banach space and assume additionaly that our sequence is convergent?

Comment: No: you could just rescale further so that $\|x_n\|=1/n$ and so the sequence converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us set $E$ to be the subspace of real sequences in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, together with the norm $||(u_n)_n||=sup_n(|u_n|)$. Consider the vectors of $E$ which consist of the sequences $u^i$ defined by $u^i_j=\delta _{i,j}$. Then all the sequences  $u^i$ have norm $1$ but the space they generate is infinite dimensional inside $E$ (it is the subspace of all sequences that are eventually 0).

Edit: I replaced "$\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$" with the space of bounded real sequences.

Comment: Ah, right. Let me correct this by considering the space of bounded sequences instead.